# Emulating a touchpad

Tags: xorg, touchpad, touchscreen

I have a Surface Pro with half of the touchscreen broken. To keep it short, is there a way for me to spawn a virtual touchpad like a virtual keyboard (`onboard`), so that I can use the tablet alone?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you trying to use a small section of the touchscreen to control the cursor over the whole screen?

Comment: @Ratler Yes, but with a touchpad behavior, as in you can drag it in one direction to move the mouse instead of teleporting the cursor there (like a touchpad)

Comment: See posted answer for details: I think the response time for a touchpad-like behaviour would make it unusable, but maybe somebody more technical than me could make it work. If you want more specific help from people, I suggest including more details about your system in the question (e.g., which GUI are you using?).

Answer (score 2):

**Executive summary**

To answer the question "if there is a way", I would say that my **guess** is that, yes, it is theoretically possible. But the details of how to do it is a question for users more advanced than me. I'm also guessing that the solution wouldn't be very practical (both in implementation and usage)  and that it would be more efficient to repair/replace the touchscreen.

**Explanation**

Having said that, here's why I'm saying it's possible.

One of the properties of the device is a "Coordinate Transformation Matrix", which you can see and change with `xinput`. This matrix maps the physical sensors of the touchscreen to the screen locations of the display system. In normal operation, that matrix is the [identity matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix), so the mapping is one-to-one (i.e., where you touch the screen is where the action is registered on the display). This matrix is used, for example, when you rotate the screen: together with the display output being rotated, the matrix changes to an appropriate rotation matrix so that the display output still matches where you physically touch the screen.

This means that you should also be able to define a more general transformation matrix that maps a small rectangular area on the physical screen to the whole display.

So it should be possible to write a program in your GUI that pops up a small, rectangular window (that's always on top so it won't disappear when you click somewhere else) and at the same time, runs `xinput` to update the Coordinate Transformation Matrix accordingly so that it maps the touchscreen sensors in that rectangular area to the whole display output.

To be clear, what I described up to here means it wouldn't work exactly like a touchpad. On a touchpad, if you put your finger at the bottom and drag it up, the cursor moves up; if you touch the bottom again and drag it up, the cursor would continue from where it was to go further up (i.e., it moves relatively to the point of contact). On the virtual touchpad I described, if you touched the bottom, the cursor would go to the corresponding part at the bottom of the display. **To go further and make it behave like a touchpad**, you could make the program change the matrix on-the-fly on each touch so that the contact point would match the current position of the cursor. But I'm guessing the response time would make this not really usable.

I don't know much about GUI programming, so this is not trivial for me, but it may be different for you. The other part, which is having your program calculate the correct matrix, involves some basic linear algebra. So you can judge how easy it is for you to implement a solution.

By the way, I've been talking about implementing this solution yourself because your problem is so specialised that I can't imagine there are ready-made tools out there; but I could be wrong!

To go even further, even if you did get something like I describe above, I can see two practical issues:

- The virtual touchpad would consume a chunk of your display (but, perhaps, you could change the opacity of the touchpad window to semi-transparent in order to be able to use the display area under it).
- Since you'd be mapping a smaller area to a larger area, depending on the sensor resolution vs your display resolution, it might not give you enough accuracy and fine control to make it practical.

In conclusion: repair/replace your touchscreen!

Comment: I have already tried the Coordination Matrix method and it wasn't very practical (at all). Which is why I'm asking for a touchpad, as I can drag to move the mouse and not estimate where things are on my "touch area".

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a [pretty good solution on GitLab](https://gitlab.com/CalcProgrammer1/TouchpadEmulator). It emulates a touchpad on the screen:

- Drag finger across screen → move cursor
- Tap then drag → left-click drag with cursor
- Hold one finger, tap another → right-click
- Volume up button → touchpad mouse mode
- Volume down button → touchscreen mode, if already in touchscreen mode: toggles on-screen keyboard on/off
- Holding either volume button for 3 sec → close touchpad app

###### Note:

That touchpad is currently only optimized for PinePhone, you *might* want to change your copy of the source code before compiling. The creator of the touchpad application states in the README that they want to implement that as a config file sooner or later so it's easier to use it on another system.